# Could not instantiate class named UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ios6, uicollectionview

"`Could not instantiate class named UICollectionView`" I am new to iOS6 please explain why the above error is coming?

I am getting this error when i trying to convert the `StoryBoard` project for [UIViewCollection](http://www.raywenderlich.com/22417/beginning-uicollectionview-in-ios-6-part-22)
to nib using this [example](http://yashesh87.wordpress.com/2012/09/12/uicollectionview-sample-code/)

Comment: You should post some code so maybe we can see where the error comes from

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using ios5 simulator, when i changed the simulator to iOS6 it worked.
It was corrected a long before,forgot to update on stackOverflow.
Thanks for answer anyways.
+1 for user1034669.

Answer (score 9):

You are probably running your app with an iOS version below 6.0 - upgrade your device or use the appropriate iOS Simulator version.